# what's the difference between *zoom and zoom?

Tags: css, zooming

in the reset part of bootstrap there is a

```
.clearfix {
*zoom: 1;
}
```

may I ask what's the difference here between *zoom and  zoom?

I appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's a css hack, which means it's only apply to ie7 and below.
you could get the detail refer here:http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks#unrecommended-asterisk_prefix

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_filter#Star_hack

I think this is here to fix IE.